# Create sample vector data in R with a skewed distribution with limited range

Tags: r, sample

I want to create in R a sample vector of data in R, in which I can control the range of values selected, so I think I want to use sample to limit the range of values generated rather than an rnorm-type command that generates a range of values based upon the type of distribution, variance, SD, etc.

So I'm looking to do a sample with a specified range (e.g. 1-5) for a skewed distribution something like this:

```
x=rexp(100,1/10)
```

Here's what I have but does not provide a skewed distribution:

```
y=sample(1:5,234, replace=T)
```

How can I have my cake (limited range) and eat it too (skewed distribution), so to speak.

Thanks

Comment: In which direction should it be skewed? And does the sample only contain integers?

Comment: Right skewed, such that there are more records with lower values and it is only integers. But I can use the as.integer function around another function to truncate to integer format. Thanks

Comment: You can use the `prob` argument of `sample` to provide a weighting to sampled integers/

Comment: Thanks Rusan: I found this example: #boostrap sample from the same sequence with 
#probabilities that favor the numbers 1-5
prob1 <- c(rep(.15, 5), rep(.05, 5))
prob1
[1] 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 at this site http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/bootstrap.htm that gives more information on use of the prob optional option of sample. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
set.seed(3)
hist(sample(1:10, size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = 10:1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi RStudent - this is beautiful, thanks! And I also love how you wrapped the hist function around it. It's a small thing but I was calling the hist function separately after generating the vector.

Answer (score 6):

The **beta** distribution takes values from 0 to 1. If you want your values to be from 0 to 5 for instance, then you can multiply them by 5. Finally, you can get a "skewness" with the beta distribution.
For example, for the skewness you can get these three types:

[image]

And using R and beta distribution you can get similar distributions as follows. Notice that the Green Vertical line refers to mean and the Red to median:

```
x= rbeta(10000,5,2)
hist(x, main="Negative or Left Skewness", freq=FALSE)
lines(density(x), col='red', lwd=3)
abline(v = c(mean(x),median(x)),  col=c("green", "red"), lty=c(2,2), lwd=c(3, 3))
```

[image]

```
x= rbeta(10000,2,5)
hist(x, main="Positive or Right Skewness", freq=FALSE)
lines(density(x), col='red', lwd=3)
abline(v = c(mean(x),median(x)),  col=c("green", "red"), lty=c(2,2), lwd=c(3, 3))
```

[image]

```
x= rbeta(10000,5,5)
hist(x, main="Symmetrical", freq=FALSE)
lines(density(x), col='red', lwd=3)
abline(v = c(mean(x),median(x)),  col=c("green", "red"), lty=c(2,2), lwd=c(3, 3))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the combinations/choice of 2s and 5s in `rbeta(10000, 5, 2)`?

Answer (score 2):

To better see what the sample function is doing with integers, use the barplot function, not the histogram function:

```
set.seed(3)
barplot(table(sample(1:10, size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = 10:1)))
```

[image: barplot]